Is Ethereum 2's proposer selected unique, weighted and DOS-resistant?
Several pages claim that Ethereum 2's block proposer selection is unique and done in proportion to weights, yet single secret leader election is not simple. I am aware of the whisk proposal that achieves this, but it seems to me that this is just a proposal and not integrated yet. It is annoying that most explanatory docs simply talk about how one proposer is selected, when doing this at random, weighted by balance, and in a DOS-resistant manner (only proposer knows until he reveals his block) is not trivial.
So my question is: Is Ethereum 2's proposer selected unique, weighted and DOS-resistant? How does the selection of the block proposer actually work?
